# setting dojo innerHTML gives syntax error

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, innerhtml

I have an html-template (will be used to design email template in app) at the client downloaded from ajax and is stored in a variable in javascript.

Now when I try to set my:

```
div.innerHTML=var1;
```

it throws a very strange Syntax error.

when I tried the same with dojo:

```
dojo.place(var1, div, "replace");
```

same error!

The html does not have any script in it, no tables, but only divs and a few event maps, i.e. onblur="funcInactive(this)". The syntax is fine.

- What is the optimal way of setting innerHTML of a DIV?

Thanks

Comment: what is the value of var1 ? The problem surely is here, or your div doesn't refer to an Element

Comment: and please copy here the error. saying "same error!" won't give us any clue ...

Answer (score 2):

the HTML contained some attributes which were not valid, i.e.:

```
style="float: left"
```

instead of

```
style="float: left;"
```

and

```
onclick="javascript:this.onClick=''"
```

instead of

```
onclick="javascript:this.onClick='';"
```

Conclusion:

Internet Explorer complains it as syntax error when an innerHTML of an object is set with invalid (above example) html. Safari/FF/Chrome works ok.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of dojo.place can be a div or a DOM node, but the innerHTML receives only a string.
Aparentemente you need to add slashes in var1, if contains scripts:

```
function addslashes(str) {
    str=str.replace(/\\/g,'\\\\');
    str=str.replace(/\'/g,'\\\'');
    str=str.replace(/\"/g,'\\"');
    str=str.replace(/\0/g,'\\0');
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer GCDO, however with little reverse debugging I found the problem and I will share for the help of community.

Edit: Answer: